# htaccess exclusion for a variable URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, zen-cart

I have a Zen Cart site where I need to exclude one URL from being rewritten. The problem is that a part of the URL is different every time so I need some wildcard and I'm not sure how to do it.

This is how my URL looks like:

```
http://XXXXXX.com/index.php?zenid=9cbbba111d0e229809dbf5a0053c2486&main_page=wp_callback
```

The `zenid` characters are different every time so I'd need a rule that would NOT rewrite URLs that end with `main_page=wp_callback`.

Can anyone tell me how to do that, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add something like this above the other rewrite rules:

```
# Stop rewrite processing if the query string contains main_page=wp_callback
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} main_page=wp_callback
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are regex.
Here is the regex matching everything ending with `main_page=wp_callback` :

```
index.php.*main_page=wp_callback$
```